# Apache - if file does not exist, run script to create it, then serve it

Tags: python, apache, cgi

How can I get this to happen in Apache (with python, on Debian if it matters)?

- User submits a form
- Based on the form entries I calculate which html file to serve them (say 0101.html)
- If 0101.html exists, redirect them directly to 0101.html
- Otherwise, run a script to create 0101.html, then redirect them to it.

Thanks!

Edit: I see there was a vote to close as too broad (though no comment or suggestion). I am just looking for a minimum working example of the Apache configuration files I would need. If you want the concrete way I *think* it will be done, I think apache just needs to check if 0101.html exists, if so serve it, otherwise run cgi/myprogram.py with input argument 0101.html. Hope this helps. If not, please suggest how I can make it more specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache shouldn't care. Just serve a program that looks for the file. If it finds it it will read it (or whatever and) return results and if it doesn't find it, it will create and return the result. All can be done with a simple python file.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. Submitting the form has to run a script anyway, so that script looks for the page and generates it if it doesn't exist. No apache configuration involved. In either case the script serves as a response a redirect to the target page (a key point I didn't realize was possible -- otherwise this wouldn't work for me if the script just served a copy of the page).